# C# tic tac toe help! beginner

Tags: c#

I am a complete beginner at c# and i am making a tic tac toe game. I am having trouble understanding what is wrong with this code for my click property for each picture box i have 9 it breaks when i run it on visual studious:

```
 private void pbxSquare0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 PictureBox pct = (PictureBox)sender;
 int pic = Convert.ToInt32((pct.Name).Substring(10,1));
        count++;

 //switching the condition for each picture box
  switch (pic)
  {
              case 1:
               {
                    if (pict1 == 0) { pict1++; pbxSquare0.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict1 == 2) { pbxSquare0.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    if (pict2 == 0) { pict2++; pbxSquare1.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict2 == 2) { pbxSquare1.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    if (pict3 == 0) { pict3++; pbxSquare2.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict3 == 2) { pbxSquare2.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            case 4:
                {
                    if (pict4 == 0) { pict4++; pbxSquare3.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict4 == 2) { pbxSquare3.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            case 5:
                {
                    if (pict5 == 0) { pict5++; pbxSquare4.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict5 == 2) { pbxSquare4.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            case 6:
                {
                    if (pict6 == 0) { pict6++; pbxSquare5.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict6 == 2) { pbxSquare5.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            case 7:
                {
                    if (pict7 == 0) { pict7++; pbxSquare6.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict7 == 2) { pbxSquare7.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            case 8:
                {
                    if (pict8 == 0) { pict8++; pbxSquare7.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict8 == 2) { pbxSquare7.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            case 9:
                {
                    if (pict9 == 0) { pict9++; pbxSquare8.BackgroundImage = pictr; }
                    else if (pict9 == 2) { pbxSquare8.Enabled = false; } break;
                }
            default: break;
```

Comment: why have if and case confitions

Comment: @Seabizkit The switch controls which cell the user clicked, the if decides if it's a legal play or not.  A big violation of don't-repeat-yourself but it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't complete code but I do see a problem:

You are using the component name to figure out what box was clicked.  (Bad idea--you should be using the Tag property!)  However, the boxes are labeled 0 to 8 in that switch statement--but the box number extracted from the name is in the 1 to 9 range.

Whether this causes a crash I do not know--you don't have complete code to see what happens.

Also, look at lists or arrays to hold your boxes--there's no reason for a switch statement here.